# PHP skip for loop and continue

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

[image]

how do i achieve the above result with for / foreach loop [Picture 2]? ive googled around but could not find the answer what i want...

```
$name = array('D1','D2','D3' );

foreach ( $name as $k=> $v ) {
  $openTime3 = strtotime('10:00');
  $closeTime3 =  strtotime('15:00');

  echo '<div class="col"> <span class="header">'.$v.'</span>';

  while ( $openTime3 < $closeTime3 ) {
     if ( ( date('Hi', $openTime3) > '1030'  && date('Hi', $openTime3) < '1130' ) && $k == 1) {
        echo '<span class="body "><a href="#" class="unconfirmed">B</a></span>';
        break; /* ???? */
        // try to use continue or break, and it didnt work i above result.
     } else {
        echo '<span class="body"><a href="#" class="available">AV</a></span>';
     }

     $openTime3 = strtotime('+15 minutes', $openTime3);
  }

  echo '</div>';
}
```

css code:

```
.col { text-align: center; width: auto; float: left; }
.col > span { display: block; }
.col > span > a {height: 26px;line-height: 26px;display: block; padding: 0 10px; }
.col > span > .available { background: #D6F2F4; }
```

above code always return below result [Picture 1]:

[image]

Comment: Can you please put this in a fiddle(with css) so that we can make changes to it?

Comment: Have you considered using an actual table? With `rowspan`?

Comment: If you want to break your outer loop while in the scope of your inner loop, use `break 2`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha how do i archive that result with table rowspan?

Comment: @Grey i used break 2, but it break the next loop.

Comment: I really don't understand where are you getting your data. How do you know how long B should be, how long A, etc?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha the B[Booked], A[Available to book] .. yellow is the amount of minutes they book in the slot. its 45 minutes slot.

Comment: @boyee007: I get *that*, but where is that represented in your code?

Comment: Is always 45min slot. Ie if customer requires 90mins it will show as 2X45min or 1X90min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added unconfirmed style to your css with border color same as background. Use flag to toggle **B**

```
<style>
.col { text-align: center; width: auto; float: left; }
.col > span { display: block; }
.col > span > a {height: 26px;line-height: 26px;display: block; padding: 0 10px; }
.col > span > .available { background: #D6F2F4;border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;}
.col > span > .unconfirmed { background: #ffff99;border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;border-color: #ffff99;}

</style>
<?php
$name = array('D1','D2','D3' );
$flag=0;//Set flag off
foreach ( $name as $k=> $v ) {
  $openTime3 = strtotime('10:00');
  $closeTime3 =  strtotime('15:00');

  echo '<div class="col"> <span class="header">'.$v.'</span>';

  while ( $openTime3 < $closeTime3 ) {

     if ( ( date('Hi', $openTime3) > '1030'  && date('Hi', $openTime3) < '1130' ) && $k == 1) {

        if($flag==0){
        echo '<span class="body "><a href="#" class="unconfirmed"></a></span>';//Hide B
        $flag=1;Toggle flag on
        }else{
        echo '<span class="body "><a href="#" class="unconfirmed">B</a></span>';Show B
        $flag=0;Toggle flag off
        }

     } else {
        echo '<span class="body"><a href="#" class="available">AV</a></span>';
     }
     //$flag=1;
     $openTime3 = strtotime('+15 minutes', $openTime3);
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks.. it gives me some idea. But the yellow slot.. it could be more than 15, 30, 45, 60 minutes, etc

Answer (score 1):

if you use the break it will stop processing at the 10:45 and not print anything for 11 - 11:30.

```
D Time Result
0 14:45 AV
1 10:00 AV
1 10:15 AV
1 10:30 AV
1 10:45 B  <= Breaks Here
2 10:00 AV
```

Using continue instead of break you will need to ensure that, the time is adjusted prior to issuing the continue or you'll get a fatal error never ending loop.

```
while ( $openTime3 < $closeTime3 ) {
 if ( ( date('Hi', $openTime3) > '1030'  && date('Hi', $openTime3) < '1130' ) && $k == 1) {
    echo '<span class="body "><a href="#" class="unconfirmed">B</a></span>';
    $openTime3 = strtotime('+15 minutes', $openTime3);
    continue;
 } else {
    echo '<span class="body"><a href="#" class="available">AV</a></span>';
 }

   $openTime3 = strtotime('+15 minutes', $openTime3);
}
```

But this will not produce the results you want either as it will be 3 seperate B blocks instead of 1 B block that is increased in height;

```
1 1000 AV
1 1015 AV
1 1030 AV
1 1045 B
1 1100 B
1 1115 B
1 1130 AV
1 1145 AV
etc..
```

If you do want a single span element for the b block you'll need to calculate the number you need and adjust the height accordingly in css depending on the number needed